# This in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-dom

Ok, i have some troubles understanding the concept. Help me out!

**Parent component:Menu**

```
export class Menu extends React.Component<any,any>{
...whole bunch of stuff
 .
 .
 .some nested components in render
    render(){     
       return <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={muiTheme}>  
        <ReactGridLayout {...some_props}>
            <div key={'canvas'}>               


 <Canvas {...this.canvas}/>


             </div>
        </ReactGridLayout>   
        </MuiThemeProvider>   
   }
```

**Child component:Canvas**

```
export class Canvas extends React.Component<CanvasProps,CanvasState>{
...whole bunch of stuff
     .
     .
render(){        
        //return this.props.decorate(this.createCanvas());
        return <canvas
                width={this.width}
                height={this.height}  
                onClick={this.lock(this.setSelected)} 
                onWheel={this.lock(this.zoom)}   
                onMouseMove={this.lock(this.rotate)}
                >{this.props.title}
                </canvas>  
      };
```

**What i'm doing:**

1.Send array to *parent*(**Menu**) props, array include some parameters for menu component and props for *child*(**Canvas**).

```
let menu_props=[
            props,
            width,
            height
        ];  

        ReactDOM.render( 
            <Menu>            
                {...menu_props}
            </Menu>,  
            document.getElementById('canvas')
        );
```

2.Attach **Canvas** props from this array to this in **Menu**

```
this.canvas=this.props.children[0];   
this.width=this.props.children[1]; 
this.height=this.props.children[2];
```

3.Call `setState` from *parent*(**Menu**)

**Result**

> TypeError: this.context.clearRect is not a function
>       at Canvas.componentDidUpdate (canvas.js:63996)

**Question**: I understand that for some reason my canvas component start to referring to this of parent component, i cant understand why is this happening. How i can encapsulate scope of each individual component so he could refer to his own this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you have access to parent's `this`. However, I'm a little bit surprised why you are using `children[<index>]` instead of simply pass `menu_props` as props:

```
let menu_props = {
  canvas: props,
  width,
  height
};

ReactDOM.render( 
  <Menu { ...menu_props } />,
  document.getElementById('canvas')
);
```

And then you'll have:

```
const { canvas, width, height } = this.props;
```

in your `Canvas`. In general I don't see much of a value using `this` in React components because you have access to `this.props` in every class method. So if you need something just

```
const { <something> } = this.props;
```

Comment: I'm not using it as props because this cause different error : JSX spread child must be an array type.

Comment: Oh my god i'm just realize i'm insert this damn piece of code in a wrong place, i really should start sleeping at night, sorry